# Warning message in running the simulations on NS2

Tags: ns2

while running the following code:

```
set ns_     [new Simulator]
set tracefd     [open simple.tr w]
$ns_ trace-all $tracefd

set topo       [new Topography]

$topo load_flatgrid 500 500

create-god $val(nn)

       $ns_ node-config -adhocRouting $val(rp) \
             -llType $val(ll) \
             -macType $val(mac) \
             -ifqType $val(ifq) \
             -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
             -antType $val(ant) \
             -propType $val(prop) \
             -phyType $val(netif) \
             -channelType $val(chan) \
             -topoInstance $topo \
             -agentTrace ON \
             -routerTrace ON \
             -macTrace OFF \
             -movementTrace OFF         

    for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } {incr i} {
        set node_($i) [$ns_ node]   
        $node_($i) random-motion 0      ;# disable random motion
    }

$node_(0) set X_ 5.0
$node_(0) set Y_ 2.0
$node_(0) set Z_ 0.0

$node_(1) set X_ 390.0
$node_(1) set Y_ 385.0
$node_(1) set Z_ 0.0

$ns_ at 50.0 "$node_(1) setdest 25.0 20.0 15.0"
$ns_ at 10.0 "$node_(0) setdest 20.0 18.0 1.0"

$ns_ at 100.0 "$node_(1) setdest 490.0 480.0 15.0" 

set tcp [new Agent/TCP]
$tcp set class_ 2
set sink [new Agent/TCPSink]
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(0) $tcp
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(1) $sink
$ns_ connect $tcp $sink
set ftp [new Application/FTP]
$ftp attach-agent $tcp
$ns_ at 10.0 "$ftp start" 

for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } {incr i} {
    $ns_ at 150.0 "$node_($i) reset";
}
$ns_ at 150.0 "stop"
$ns_ at 150.01 "puts \"NS EXITING...\" ; $ns_ halt"
proc stop {} {
    global ns_ tracefd
    $ns_ flush-trace
    close $tracefd
}

puts "Starting Simulation..."
$ns_ run
```

It gives me the following warning message:
num_nodes is set 2
warning: Please use -channel as shown in tcl/ex/wireless-mitf.tcl
INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead
Starting Simulation...
channel.cc:sendUp - Calc highestAntennaZ_ and distCST_
highestAntennaZ_ = 1.5,  distCST_ = 550.0
SORTING LISTS ...DONE!
NS EXITING...

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (hint: remove the large amount of unnecessary comments from the code)

Comment: I have removed all the unnecessary comments and now it includes the code only

Comment: The code is supposed to be a Marc Greis example, ref. @Shahab Haider  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ns-users/fa-IUlkjKVg ...